# Can't resize the width of a button inside a <td>

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to resize the blue button in the header image, but I can't change its width. It's in a table format inside a `<td>` i tried using `td` width also it didn't work. It looks like its fixed to 640px. I tried with `style width` also but it still didn't work. How else can I edit the width of the blue button? See attached image[image]
As you can see the header image is what im trying to achieve

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <title>You're Invited to the SAP SuccessFactors SuccessConnect in Las Vegas</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta name="ProgId" content="Word.Document">
     
   </head>
   <body style="margin:0; padding:0;" bgcolor="#ffffff" link="#008cd2">
      <style type="text/css">
         * {
         -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
         -webkit-text-resize: 100%;
         text-resize: 100%;
         }
      </style>
      <!-- main wrapper -->
      <table data-section="body" class="wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
         <!-- header -->
         <tr>
            <td>
               <table data-section="header" class="wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                  <tr>
                     <td style="font-size:1px;color:#FFFFFF;">
                        <font color="#FFFFFF" style="font-size:1px;color:#FFFFFF;line-height:0;">
                           <!-- inbox preview optimized text -->
                           <span class="appleLinksWhite">Join SAP in Las Vegas for SuccessConnect at the Aria Resort! Hear from HR industry thought leaders, experts, and special guests.</span>
                        </font>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <table class="container header-container" title="header-container" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#000000" style="margin:0 auto !important; padding:0 20px;">
                           <tr>
                              <td>
                                 <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                       <td height="17" class="height10" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td>
                                          <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" title="brand">
                                             <tr>
                                                <td valign="middle" width="414" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;"><img src="https://portal.thinkwgroup.com/html-email/sap/email/images/logo-carlyle-group.png" alt="" border="0"style="vertical-align:top; width: 201px; height: 36px;"></a></td>
                                                <td valign="middle" align="right" width="104" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;"><a title="THE BEST RUN" href="https://www.sap.com" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="https://fm.sap.com/images/2015/run-simple-email/TheBestRunLogo-64px-White-DG.png" alt="THE BEST RUN" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" width="104" height="32" title="tagline" style="vertical-align:top; width: 104px; height: 32px;"></a></td>
                                                <td width="10" class="hide" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td valign="middle" align="right" width="72" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;"><a title="SAP" href="https://www.sap.com" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="https://fm.sap.com/images/2015/run-simple-email/logo.png" alt="SAP" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" width="72" height="36" title="logo" style="vertical-align:top; width: 72px; height: 36px;"></a></td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td height="17" class="height10" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <!-- main -->
         <tr>
            <td>
               <table data-section="main" class="wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <table class="flexible" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto !important;">
                           <tr data-section="hero">
                              <td>
                                 <table class="flexible" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto !important;">
                                    <tr class="motion-row">
                                       <td width="100%" valign="top" bgcolor="#000000">
                                          <table background="https://portal.thinkwgroup.com/html-email/sap/email/images/banner-lasvegas.jpg" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                             <tr>
                                                <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;" height="60">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td style="font:36px/44px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#ffffff;">
                                                   <span class="font22">Join SAP in Las Vegas for Success<span style='color:#f0ab00;'>Connect</span> at the Aria Resort!</span><br>
                                                </td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td align="center" bgcolor="#008fd3" width="50" height="40"><a class="font14" style="font: 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block;" href="https://events.sap.com/gb/cx-live-2019-london/en/registration.aspx?cid=10902&autoplay=off" target="_blank" data-sap-hpa-ceimo-ioi-link="73554900100700000840">Register today</a></td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <!-- main 
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="widthAuto mceEditable" style= align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#008fd3" width="250" height="40"><a class="font14" style="font: 18px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block;" href="https://events.sap.com/successconnect/en/las-vegas-2019" target="_blank" data-sap-hpa-ceimo-ioi-link="73555000100800000773">Register today &rsaquo;</a></td>
                                                    </tr>   
                                                -->
                                             <tr>
                                                <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;" height="40">&nbsp;</td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;" height="40">&nbsp;</td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td height="30" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr data-section="subhead">
                              <td>
                                 <table class="container" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto !important; padding:0 20px;">
                                    <tr>
                                       <td align="left" style="font:22px/30px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#444444;">
                                          <span class="font19">Hear from HR industry thought leaders, experts, and special guests.</span>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table class="container" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto !important; padding:0 20px;">
                           <!-- email body -->
                           <tr>
                              <td>
                                 <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr data-section="content">
                                       <td>
                                          <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                             <tr>
                                                <td style="font:14px/21px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#444444;">
                                                   <p>You are cordially invited to attend our annual&nbsp;SuccessConnec<u>t</u>&nbsp;event, held by SAP SuccessFactors this September 16&ndash;18 in Las Vegas. Regarded as one of the top HR events of the year, SuccessConnect brings industry <strong>thought leaders</strong>, current and prospective <strong>customers</strong>, <strong>technology partners</strong>, and <strong>solutions experts</strong> together to share their <strong>experiences</strong>, <strong>best practices</strong>, and <strong>innovations</strong>. The event offers more than 100 breakout sessions alongside many <strong>high-level networking opportunities</strong>.</p>
                                                   <p class="xmsonormal">The future workplace looks very different from what we see today. From technological advancements to the ever-changing nature of jobs, skills, and careers, businesses need to find ways to succeed in a world that&rsquo;s being reshaped by continuous innovation and disruption.&nbsp;Learn how SAP SuccessFactors solutions can help your company right now and help <strong>plan for future initiatives</strong>.</p>
                                                   <hr>
                                                   <p></p>
                                                   <table class="template-2col image-l split50 mceNonEditable" style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                      <tbody>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td class="hide-email mceEditable" style="vertical-align: top; font: 14px/21px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #444444;" valign="top" width="50%">
                                                               <p><img class="photo" src="https://portal.thinkwgroup.com/html-email/sap/email/images/image-lasvegas.jpg" width="280" height="158" /></p>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="mobile-block2 mceEditable" style="vertical-align: top; font: 14px/21px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #444444;" width="50%">
                                                               <p>This event provides a fantastic forum to meet other HR professionals and find out how they&rsquo;re using SAP SuccessFactors to help <strong>drive a digital HR strategy</strong>, transform talent, recruitment, and learning programs, as well as <strong>improve HR process efficiency</strong>.</p>
                                                            </td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td colspan="2" valign="middle" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                      </tbody>
                                                   </table>
                                                   <p class="xmsonormal">Enjoy a celebratory evening at KAOS nightclub in the iconic Palms Resort Casino, where you&rsquo;ll get to network with your peers while enjoying great entertainment.</p>
                                                   <p><a href="https://events.sap.com/successconnect/en/las-vegas-2019" target="_blank" data-sap-hpa-ceimo-ioi-link="73555000100800000774"><strong>Please register here.</strong></a></p>
                                                   <p>We look forward to seeing you in Las Vegas!</p>
                                                   <table class="mceNonEditable" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                      <tbody>
                                                         <tr data-section="callout">
                                                            <td>
                                                               <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f5f5f5">
                                                                  <tbody>
                                                                     <tr>
                                                                        <td style="line-height: 1px; font-size: 1px;" height="16">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                     </tr>
                                                                     <tr>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                           <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                              <tbody>
                                                                                 <tr>
                                                                                    <td class="width20 " width="42">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                                    <td class="mceEditable" style="font: 14px/21px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #444444;">
                                                                                       <p><strong>SAP SuccessFactors SuccessConnect</strong></p>
                                                                                       <p><strong>Date:</strong><br />September 16&ndash;18, 2019</p>
                                                                                       <p><strong>Location:</strong><br />Aria Resort and Casino</p>
                                                                                       <p><strong>Address:</strong><br />3730 S Las Vegas Blvd<br />Las Vegas, NV 89158</p>
                                                                                       <table class="cta-button mceNonEditable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                                          <tbody>
                                                                                             <tr>
                                                                                                <td class="widthAuto mceEditable" style="border-radius: 5px;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#008fd3" width="250" height="40"><a class="font14" style="font: 18px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block;" href="https://events.sap.com/successconnect/en/las-vegas-2019" target="_blank" data-sap-hpa-ceimo-ioi-link="73555000100800000773">Register today &rsaquo;</a></td>
                                                                                             </tr>
                                                                                             <tr>
                                                                                                <td style="line-height: 1px; font-size: 1px;" height="15">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                                             </tr>
                                                                                          </tbody>
                                                                                       </table>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td class="width20 " width="42">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                                 </tr>
                                                                              </tbody>
                                                                           </table>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                     </tr>
                                                                     <tr>
                                                                        <td style="line-height: 1px; font-size: 1px;" height="16">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                     </tr>
                                                                  </tbody>
                                                               </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                      </tbody>
                                                   </table>
                                                </td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td height="35" class="height28" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <div style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px/2px courier; color:#ffffff;">- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -</div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>

      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't overload us with information. Is that whole image necessary. There are two blue buttons, which is the problematic button? Perhaps just trim the image so the problem is immediately obvious. The same goes for your code, do we really need 222 lines of code to illustrate the problem. Finally, you need to [get rid of the table based layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html) and inline CSS. The `table` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change you code

From

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#008fd3" width="50" height="40"><a class="font14" style="font: 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block;" href="https://events.sap.com/gb/cx-live-2019-london/en/registration.aspx?cid=10902&autoplay=off" target="_blank" data-sap-hpa-ceimo-ioi-link="73554900100700000840">Register today</a></td>
```

to

```
    <td width="50" height="40" bgcolor="#202020" align="center">    
    <a class="font14" style="font: 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block;background: #008fd3;width: 20%;position: absolute;padding: 8px;" href="https://events.sap.com/gb/cx-live-2019-london/en/registration.aspx?cid=10902&amp;autoplay=off" target="_blank" rel="noopener" data-sap-hpa-ceimo-ioi-link="73554900100700000840" data-mce-href="https://events.sap.com/gb/cx-live-2019-london/en/registration.aspx?cid=10902&amp;autoplay=off" data-mce-style="font: 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block;" data-mce-selected="1">Register today</a>
 </td>
```

Hope can help you

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `display:block`

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>You're Invited to the SAP SuccessFactors SuccessConnect in Las Vegas</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="ProgId" content="Word.Document">

</head>

<body style="margin:0; padding:0;" bgcolor="#ffffff" link="#008cd2">
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
      -webkit-text-resize: 100%;
      text-resize: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- main wrapper -->
  <table data-section="body" class="wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <!-- header -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table data-section="header" class="wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
          <tr>
            <td style="font-size:1px;color:#FFFFFF;">
              <font color="#FFFFFF" style="font-size:1px;color:#FFFFFF;line-height:0;">
                <!-- inbox preview optimized text -->
                <span class="appleLinksWhite">Join SAP in Las Vegas for SuccessConnect at the Aria Resort! Hear from HR industry thought leaders, experts, and special guests.</span>
              </font>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table class="container header-container" title="header-container" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#000000" style="margin:0 auto !important; padding:0 20px;">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td height="17" class="height10" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" title="brand">
                            <tr>
                              <td valign="middle" width="414" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;"><img src="https://portal.thinkwgroup.com/html-email/sap/email/images/logo-carlyle-group.png" alt="" border="0" style="vertical-align:top; width: 201px; height: 36px;"></a>
                              </td>
                              <td valign="middle" align="right" width="104" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;">
                                <a title="THE BEST RUN" href="https://www.sap.com" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="https://fm.sap.com/images/2015/run-simple-email/TheBestRunLogo-64px-White-DG.png" alt="THE BEST RUN" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" width="104" height="32" title="tagline" style="vertical-align:top; width: 104px; height: 32px;"></a>
                              </td>
                              <td width="10" class="hide" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td valign="middle" align="right" width="72" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;">
                                <a title="SAP" href="https://www.sap.com" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="https://fm.sap.com/images/2015/run-simple-email/logo.png" alt="SAP" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" width="72" height="36" title="logo" style="vertical-align:top; width: 72px; height: 36px;"></a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td height="17" class="height10" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- main -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table data-section="main" class="wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table class="flexible" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto !important;">
                <tr data-section="hero">
                  <td>
                    <table class="flexible" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto !important;">
                      <tr class="motion-row">
                        <td width="100%" valign="top" bgcolor="#000000">
                          <table background="https://portal.thinkwgroup.com/html-email/sap/email/images/banner-lasvegas.jpg" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;" height="60">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="font:36px/44px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#ffffff;">
                                <span class="font22">Join SAP in Las Vegas for Success<span style='color:#f0ab00;'>Connect</span> at the Aria Resort!</span><br>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="left" width="50" height="40">
                                <a class="font14" style="font: 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; background:#008fd3;    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 1em;" href="https://events.sap.com/gb/cx-live-2019-london/en/registration.aspx?cid=10902&autoplay=off"
                                    target="_blank" data-sap-hpa-ceimo-ioi-link="73554900100700000840">Register today</a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- main 
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="widthAuto mceEditable" style= align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#008fd3" width="250" height="40"><a class="font14" style="font: 18px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block;" href="https://events.sap.com/successconnect/en/las-vegas-2019" target="_blank" data-sap-hpa-ceimo-ioi-link="73555000100800000773">Register today &rsaquo;</a></td>
                                                    </tr>   
                                                -->
                            <tr>
                              <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;" height="40">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;" height="40">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="30" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-section="subhead">
                  <td>
                    <table class="container" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto !important; padding:0 20px;">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="font:22px/30px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#444444;">
                          <span class="font19">Hear from HR industry thought leaders, experts, and special guests.</span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table class="container" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto !important; padding:0 20px;">
                <!-- email body -->
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr data-section="content">
                        <td>
                          <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                              <td style="font:14px/21px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#444444;">
                                <p>You are cordially invited to attend our annual&nbsp;SuccessConnec<u>t</u>&nbsp;event, held by SAP SuccessFactors this September 16&ndash;18 in Las Vegas. Regarded as one of the top HR events of the year, SuccessConnect
                                  brings industry <strong>thought leaders</strong>, current and prospective <strong>customers</strong>, <strong>technology partners</strong>, and <strong>solutions experts</strong> together to share their <strong>experiences</strong>,
                                  <strong>best practices</strong>, and <strong>innovations</strong>. The event offers more than 100 breakout sessions alongside many <strong>high-level networking opportunities</strong>.</p>
                                <p class="xmsonormal">The future workplace looks very different from what we see today. From technological advancements to the ever-changing nature of jobs, skills, and careers, businesses need to find ways to succeed in a world that&rsquo;s
                                  being reshaped by continuous innovation and disruption.&nbsp;Learn how SAP SuccessFactors solutions can help your company right now and help <strong>plan for future initiatives</strong>.</p>
                                <hr>
                                <p></p>
                                <table class="template-2col image-l split50 mceNonEditable" style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td class="hide-email mceEditable" style="vertical-align: top; font: 14px/21px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #444444;" valign="top" width="50%">
                                        <p><img class="photo" src="https://portal.thinkwgroup.com/html-email/sap/email/images/image-lasvegas.jpg" width="280" height="158" /></p>
                                      </td>
                                      <td class="mobile-block2 mceEditable" style="vertical-align: top; font: 14px/21px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #444444;" width="50%">
                                        <p>This event provides a fantastic forum to meet other HR professionals and find out how they&rsquo;re using SAP SuccessFactors to help <strong>drive a digital HR strategy</strong>, transform talent, recruitment, and
                                          learning programs, as well as <strong>improve HR process efficiency</strong>.</p>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td colspan="2" valign="middle" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <p class="xmsonormal">Enjoy a celebratory evening at KAOS nightclub in the iconic Palms Resort Casino, where you&rsquo;ll get to network with your peers while enjoying great entertainment.</p>
                                <p><a href="https://events.sap.com/successconnect/en/las-vegas-2019" target="_blank" data-sap-hpa-ceimo-ioi-link="73555000100800000774"><strong>Please register here.</strong></a></p>
                                <p>We look forward to seeing you in Las Vegas!</p>
                                <table class="mceNonEditable" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr data-section="callout">
                                      <td>
                                        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f5f5f5">
                                          <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td style="line-height: 1px; font-size: 1px;" height="16">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td>
                                                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                  <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                      <td class="width20 " width="42">&nbsp;</td>
                                                      <td class="mceEditable" style="font: 14px/21px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #444444;">
                                                        <p><strong>SAP SuccessFactors SuccessConnect</strong></p>
                                                        <p><strong>Date:</strong><br />September 16&ndash;18, 2019</p>
                                                        <p><strong>Location:</strong><br />Aria Resort and Casino</p>
                                                        <p><strong>Address:</strong><br />3730 S Las Vegas Blvd<br />Las Vegas, NV 89158</p>
                                                        <table class="cta-button mceNonEditable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                          <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td class="widthAuto mceEditable" style="border-radius: 5px;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#008fd3" width="250" height="40"><a class="font14" style="font: 18px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block;" href="https://events.sap.com/successconnect/en/las-vegas-2019"
                                                                  target="_blank" data-sap-hpa-ceimo-ioi-link="73555000100800000773">Register today &rsaquo;</a></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                              <td style="line-height: 1px; font-size: 1px;" height="15">&nbsp;</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                          </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                      </td>
                                                      <td class="width20 " width="42">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                              </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td style="line-height: 1px; font-size: 1px;" height="16">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td height="35" class="height28" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px/2px courier; color:#ffffff;">- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <title>You're Invited to the SAP SuccessFactors SuccessConnect in Las Vegas</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta name="ProgId" content="Word.Document">
     
   </head>
   <body style="margin:0; padding:0;" bgcolor="#ffffff" link="#008cd2">
      <style type="text/css">
         * {
         -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
         -webkit-text-resize: 100%;
         text-resize: 100%;
         }
      </style>
      <!-- main wrapper -->
      <table data-section="body" class="wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
         <!-- header -->
         <tr>
            <td>
               <table data-section="header" class="wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                  <tr>
                     <td style="font-size:1px;color:#FFFFFF;">
                        <font color="#FFFFFF" style="font-size:1px;color:#FFFFFF;line-height:0;">
                           <!-- inbox preview optimized text -->
                           <span class="appleLinksWhite">Join SAP in Las Vegas for SuccessConnect at the Aria Resort! Hear from HR industry thought leaders, experts, and special guests.</span>
                        </font>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <table class="container header-container" title="header-container" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#000000" style="margin:0 auto !important; padding:0 20px;">
                           <tr>
                              <td>
                                 <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                       <td height="17" class="height10" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td>
                                          <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" title="brand">
                                             <tr>
                                                <td valign="middle" width="414" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;"><img src="https://portal.thinkwgroup.com/html-email/sap/email/images/logo-carlyle-group.png" alt="" border="0"style="vertical-align:top; width: 201px; height: 36px;"></a></td>
                                                <td valign="middle" align="right" width="104" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;"><a title="THE BEST RUN" href="https://www.sap.com" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="https://fm.sap.com/images/2015/run-simple-email/TheBestRunLogo-64px-White-DG.png" alt="THE BEST RUN" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" width="104" height="32" title="tagline" style="vertical-align:top; width: 104px; height: 32px;"></a></td>
                                                <td width="10" class="hide" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td valign="middle" align="right" width="72" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;"><a title="SAP" href="https://www.sap.com" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="https://fm.sap.com/images/2015/run-simple-email/logo.png" alt="SAP" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" width="72" height="36" title="logo" style="vertical-align:top; width: 72px; height: 36px;"></a></td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td height="17" class="height10" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <!-- main -->
         <tr>
            <td>
               <table data-section="main" class="wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <table class="flexible" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto !important;">
                           <tr data-section="hero">
                              <td>
                                 <table class="flexible" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto !important;">
                                    <tr class="motion-row">
                                       <td width="100%" valign="top" bgcolor="#000000">
                                          <table background="https://portal.thinkwgroup.com/html-email/sap/email/images/banner-lasvegas.jpg" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                             <tr>
                                                <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;" height="60">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td style="font:36px/44px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#ffffff;">
                                                   <span class="font22">Join SAP in Las Vegas for Success<span style='color:#f0ab00;'>Connect</span> at the Aria Resort!</span><br>
                                                </td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                               <td align="center" bgcolor="#008fd3" width="50" height="40" style="width: 20%;display: block;"><a class="font14" style="font: 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #ffffff;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;display: block;width: 100%;padding: 10px 0px;" href="https://events.sap.com/gb/cx-live-2019-london/en/registration.aspx?cid=10902&amp;autoplay=off" target="_blank" data-sap-hpa-ceimo-ioi-link="73554900100700000840">Register today</a></td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <!-- main 
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="widthAuto mceEditable" style= align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#008fd3" width="250" height="40"><a class="font14" style="font: 18px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block;" href="https://events.sap.com/successconnect/en/las-vegas-2019" target="_blank" data-sap-hpa-ceimo-ioi-link="73555000100800000773">Register today &rsaquo;</a></td>
                                                    </tr>   
                                                -->
                                             <tr>
                                                <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;" height="40">&nbsp;</td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <tr>
                                                <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;" height="40">&nbsp;</td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td height="30" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr data-section="subhead">
                              <td>
                                 <table class="container" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto !important; padding:0 20px;">
                                    <tr>
                                       <td align="left" style="font:22px/30px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#444444;">
                                          <span class="font19">Hear from HR industry thought leaders, experts, and special guests.</span>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table class="container" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto !important; padding:0 20px;">
                           <!-- email body -->
                           <tr>
                              <td>
                                 <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr data-section="content">
                                       <td>
                                          <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                             <tr>
                                                <td style="font:14px/21px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#444444;">
                                                   <p>You are cordially invited to attend our annual&nbsp;SuccessConnec<u>t</u>&nbsp;event, held by SAP SuccessFactors this September 16&ndash;18 in Las Vegas. Regarded as one of the top HR events of the year, SuccessConnect brings industry <strong>thought leaders</strong>, current and prospective <strong>customers</strong>, <strong>technology partners</strong>, and <strong>solutions experts</strong> together to share their <strong>experiences</strong>, <strong>best practices</strong>, and <strong>innovations</strong>. The event offers more than 100 breakout sessions alongside many <strong>high-level networking opportunities</strong>.</p>
                                                   <p class="xmsonormal">The future workplace looks very different from what we see today. From technological advancements to the ever-changing nature of jobs, skills, and careers, businesses need to find ways to succeed in a world that&rsquo;s being reshaped by continuous innovation and disruption.&nbsp;Learn how SAP SuccessFactors solutions can help your company right now and help <strong>plan for future initiatives</strong>.</p>
                                                   <hr>
                                                   <p></p>
                                                   <table class="template-2col image-l split50 mceNonEditable" style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                      <tbody>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td class="hide-email mceEditable" style="vertical-align: top; font: 14px/21px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #444444;" valign="top" width="50%">
                                                               <p><img class="photo" src="https://portal.thinkwgroup.com/html-email/sap/email/images/image-lasvegas.jpg" width="280" height="158" /></p>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="mobile-block2 mceEditable" style="vertical-align: top; font: 14px/21px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #444444;" width="50%">
                                                               <p>This event provides a fantastic forum to meet other HR professionals and find out how they&rsquo;re using SAP SuccessFactors to help <strong>drive a digital HR strategy</strong>, transform talent, recruitment, and learning programs, as well as <strong>improve HR process efficiency</strong>.</p>
                                                            </td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                         <tr>
                                                            <td colspan="2" valign="middle" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                      </tbody>
                                                   </table>
                                                   <p class="xmsonormal">Enjoy a celebratory evening at KAOS nightclub in the iconic Palms Resort Casino, where you&rsquo;ll get to network with your peers while enjoying great entertainment.</p>
                                                   <p><a href="https://events.sap.com/successconnect/en/las-vegas-2019" target="_blank" data-sap-hpa-ceimo-ioi-link="73555000100800000774"><strong>Please register here.</strong></a></p>
                                                   <p>We look forward to seeing you in Las Vegas!</p>
                                                   <table class="mceNonEditable" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                      <tbody>
                                                         <tr data-section="callout">
                                                            <td>
                                                               <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f5f5f5">
                                                                  <tbody>
                                                                     <tr>
                                                                        <td style="line-height: 1px; font-size: 1px;" height="16">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                     </tr>
                                                                     <tr>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                           <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                              <tbody>
                                                                                 <tr>
                                                                                    <td class="width20 " width="42">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                                    <td class="mceEditable" style="font: 14px/21px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #444444;">
                                                                                       <p><strong>SAP SuccessFactors SuccessConnect</strong></p>
                                                                                       <p><strong>Date:</strong><br />September 16&ndash;18, 2019</p>
                                                                                       <p><strong>Location:</strong><br />Aria Resort and Casino</p>
                                                                                       <p><strong>Address:</strong><br />3730 S Las Vegas Blvd<br />Las Vegas, NV 89158</p>
                                                                                       <table class="cta-button mceNonEditable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                                          <tbody>
                                                                                             <tr>
                                                                                                <td class="widthAuto mceEditable" style="border-radius: 5px;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#008fd3" width="250" height="40"><a class="font14" style="font: 18px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block;" href="https://events.sap.com/successconnect/en/las-vegas-2019" target="_blank" data-sap-hpa-ceimo-ioi-link="73555000100800000773">Register today &rsaquo;</a></td>
                                                                                             </tr>
                                                                                             <tr>
                                                                                                <td style="line-height: 1px; font-size: 1px;" height="15">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                                             </tr>
                                                                                          </tbody>
                                                                                       </table>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td class="width20 " width="42">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                                 </tr>
                                                                              </tbody>
                                                                           </table>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                     </tr>
                                                                     <tr>
                                                                        <td style="line-height: 1px; font-size: 1px;" height="16">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                     </tr>
                                                                  </tbody>
                                                               </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                      </tbody>
                                                   </table>
                                                </td>
                                             </tr>
                                          </table>
                                       </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                       <td height="35" class="height28" style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                 </table>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <div style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px/2px courier; color:#ffffff;">- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -</div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>

      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#008fd3" width="50" height="40" style="width: 20%;display: block;">
       <a class="font14" style="font: 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #ffffff;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;display: block;width: 100%;padding: 10px 0px;" href="https://events.sap.com/gb/cx-live-2019-london/en/registration.aspx?cid=10902&amp;autoplay=off" target="_blank" data-sap-hpa-ceimo-ioi-link="73554900100700000840">Register today</a>
</td>
```

simple My code Replease To Your Code

Comment: What your code will do? How this code will help to fix his issue? Can you add a precise description?